# Creating ribbons in Power Point for content pane add-ins

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I am trying to create a content pane add-in for power point that includes ribbons with add-in commands. I have looked at the [Create add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands) tutorial as well as the examples [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples).

The add-ins in examples and tutorials that I'm able to find are all task pane add-ins. Is there a way to create content pane add-in with add-in commands and ribbons?

Following the tutorials, I have been able to create the commands for task pane add-ins. However, when I change the OfficeApp xsi:type from "TaskPaneApp" to "ContentApp", the add-in ribbon does not appear anymore. I believe this is because the schema I am using in VersionOverrides is not compatible with content apps.

Is there a VersionOverride schema for content pane add-ins? I have only been able to find http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides and http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides.

Answer (score 2):

Add-in Commands are currently only supported with Task Pane Add-ins.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#supported-platforms):

> Content add-ins do not currently support add-in commands.